# Is there a half log function?

Tags: logarithms

Is there a half log function $f(x)$ such that $f ( f(x) ) = \ln x$ (or $\log x$ with any base). More generally, is there partial logarithmic function to perform $0.5, 0.3, \pi$ etc of a log function?

Thank you.

Comment: For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$f(f(xy))=f(f(x))+f(f(y)) $$ i.e. $f\circ f$ is a group homomorphism $f\circ f:(\mathbb{R}^{+},\times)\to (\mathbb{R},+)$

Comment: I would think that the inverse of a [half-exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function) ought to do the trick.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this site about functional square roots which would cover the base case of your question.